# Expand an image when user hovers or clicks - with minimal effort

Tags: php, javascript, css

I want to expand an image on a web page when the user clicks it or even hovers his cursor over it.

I suspect that this needs a JavaScript solution and I know nothing of JS, so wouldn't know where to bein.

Can anyone suggest a free solution with minimal install, learning curve or coding effort on my part?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And this .. http://cssdemos.tupence.co.uk/image-popup.htm

Comment: I made your tags correct, this is not PHP, this is javascript and/or css. Its based on what you want exactly...

Comment: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ would be the standard for doing this.

Comment: @j-man86 (+1) Why not post that as an answer, in case that's what I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers as suggested before would meet your needs if that is the desired effect you require. You can enlarge with CSS though.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/mUpJZ/

```
img {
    width:90px;
}
img:hover {
    width:500px;
}
```

This is just a basic example but you could make it as elaborate as you wish, eg positioning, shadow effect ect etc, when `:hover`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Just give your image a class, and you can simply target it in your javascript with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // expand on click
    $('.my_image').click(function(){
    $(this).css({'height' : '500px', 'width' : '500px'}) 
    });
    // expand on hover
    $('.my_image').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'height' : '500px', 'width' : '500px'}) 
    });

)}
```

Obviously setting it to whatever dimensions you wish for it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a [light box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29)

[This one](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/) looks pretty easy I guess.